# Running Android Emulator without Open Gl 2.0

Tags: android, performance

I have a 3gb ram laptop which doesn't contain the graphic card i.e;Open Gl 2.0 is not avialable.So i am not able to use genymotion;so i think to go android x86 ;in there i dint find a any hardware specification; is that will compiatable in my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found  in case of cross platform application we can run file as html source